# Dagger2 compilation error in MVVM Factory when defining injector for fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, dagger-2

I have a next root component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AndroidInjectionModule::class,
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, 
        ActivityBuilderModule::class])
interface RootComponent : AndroidInjector<DaggerApplication> {
    fun inject(myApplication: MyApplication)
    override fun inject(photoPartyApplication: DaggerApplication)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder
        fun build(): RootComponent
    }
}
```

In ActivityBuilderModule:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilderModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainActivityModule::class,
            ViewModelModule::class])
    @ActivityScope
    abstract fun bindMainActivity(): MainActivity

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [SecondaryActivityModule::class,
            ViewModelModule::class,
            FragmentBuilderModule::class])
    @ActivityScope
    abstract fun bindSecondaryActivity(): SecondaryActivity

}
```

`ViewModelModule` is a trivial module to help making constructor injections in `ViewModel` classes and consists of `@Binds` between specific instances and `ViewModel` type.

`MainActivityModule` and `SecondaryActivityModule` define specific dependencies for corresponding activities.

The key thing is that when I added this **FragmentBuilderModule** - compilation started to emit errors. The stack trace is the next:

> error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] some_package.SpecificDependency cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
>
> public abstract interface RootComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector {
>
> ^
>
> A binding with matching key exists in component: some_package.ActivityBuilderModule_BindMainActivity.MainActivitySubcomponent
>
> some_package.SpecificDependency is injected at some_package.MainViewModel(specificDependency, …)
>
> some_package.MainViewModel is injected at some_package.ViewModelModule.mainViewModel(viewModel)
>
> ```
> Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> is injected at
>       some_package.ViewModelFactory(viewModelProviders)
> ```
>
> some_package.ViewModelFactory is injected at some_package.ViewModelModule.bindViewModelFactory(factory)
>
> android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory is injected at some_package.MyFragment.viewModelFactory
>
> some_package.MyFragment is injected at dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)
>
> [some_package.RootComponent → some_package.ActivityBuilderModule_BindSecondaryActivity.SecondaryActivitySubcomponent → some_package.FragmentBuilderModule_ProvideMyFragmentFactoryMyFragmentSubcomponent]

As far as I can understand, Dagger assumes that the whole dependencies graph has to be properly constructed for the `map` of `Class<? extends ViewModel> -> Provider<ViewModel>`, and if some `ViewModels` fall into `factory`, and that `factory` is injected into a component, then if component will ask for **any** `viewmodel`, **it has to be delivered**. And in order to deliver all the `viewmodels`, again, all the dependencies have to be available (what's not true, because specific dependency for the `MainViewModel` is available only from `MainModule`, and that's what dagger says before the stack trace).

Is there a workaround to provide dependencies to the `map` of `Class<? extends ViewModel> -> Provider<ViewModel>` on demand instead of building the whole graph at compile time (which is leading to the compile-time error)

Answer (score 0):

> First add ViewModelModule at RootComponent

```
 @Singleton
 @Component(modules = [AndroidInjectionModule::class,
            AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, 
            ActivityBuilderModule::class,
            ViewModelModule::class])                 // add this so you don't have to add for every activity
    interface RootComponent : AndroidInjector<DaggerApplication> {
        fun inject(myApplication: MyApplication)
        override fun inject(photoPartyApplication: DaggerApplication)

        @Component.Builder
        interface Builder {
            @BindsInstance
            fun application(application: Application): Builder
            fun build(): RootComponent
        }
    }
```

> Now in ActivityBuilderModule add only activty

```
 @Module
 abstract class ActivityBuilderModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    @ActivityScope
    abstract fun bindMainActivity(): MainActivity
 }
```

> Now In ViewModelModule add all ViewModel

```
 @Module
 abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(MainActivityModule::class)
    abstract fun bindMainActivityViewModel(mainActivityViewModel: MainActivityModule): ViewModel
}
```

> Add ViewModelKey

```
 @MustBeDocumented
 @kotlin.annotation.Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER)
 @kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
 @MapKey
 internal annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)
```

> And ViewModelFactory

```
@Singleton
class KotlinViewModelFactory @Inject
constructor(private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        var creator: Provider<out ViewModel>? = creators[modelClass]
        if (creator == null) {
            for ((key, value) in creators) {
                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(key)) {
                    creator = value
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        if (creator == null) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass")
        }
        try {
            Timber.d(creator.toString())
            return creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }
}
```